# External hard drive shows partly full although there are no files on it

Tags: external-hard-drive

I want to reformat an external hard drive and for this purpose I saved all files I had on it onto my internal hard drive.

But although I deleted all files from the hard drive, in the explorer it still shows around 17gb of the ~100gb drive are full. I have activated showing hidden folders, but it's still empty.

Now this doesn't stop me from formatting the drive, but I don't want to accidentally delete something that I just don't see.

Why is the drive not empty and is this normal? Can I safely format it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have Explorer visible (above), hold down `Àlt` and while holding it type `v` then `e` and finally `o` - This should be equal to `Menu: View > Explorer bar > Folders` - Then, within the list of folders, find Trashcan and **right**-click it, select `Empty trashcan` - re-check the free/used space.

Comment: Change your `Windows Expolorer` settings to display hidden files.

Comment: @Hannu My OS is German so the shortcuts are different, and I couldn't find the associated options. Does your suggestion come down to the same thing as D Schlachter's answer, to delete the recycle bin folder?

Comment: Yes, but only the CONTENT - not the folder itself.

Comment: *... and the usefulness to keep English as OS-language has proven itself once more*

Comment: @Hannu Only if you ask for help on English sites, that is ;D Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: I had a similar thing happen here - http://superuser.com/questions/948456/win-8-1-made-new-vhds-txts-copied-to-d-partition-of-another-machine-on-boot - No matter which hidden and system files folders I opened up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've selected **Show hidden files, folders, and drives**, but be sure to also *deselect* **Hide protected operating system files** (in Folder Options > View). Otherwise, you're getting an incomplete view.

(Cf. [How to delete $RECYCLE.BIN folder on external hard disk?](https://superuser.com/questions/564442/how-to-delete-recycle-bin-folder-on-external-hard-disk))

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I deleted the recycle bin folders, and now there is only a "System Volume Information" folder that I can't delete. It still shows 6gb full. Just out of curiosity, could I do anything about this rest as well?

Comment: I understand it's [mostly System Restore points and such](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/20/55764.aspx). The preferred way to clean it is to [use Disk Cleanup](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/818-disk-cleanup-open-use.html).

Comment: @DSchlachter - http://superuser.com/questions/948456/win-8-1-made-new-vhds-txts-copied-to-d-partition-of-another-machine-on-boot - I did this and still cant find a way to see the files taking space.