# How to create a $RECYCLE.BIN folder on external hard disk?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

Just the opposite of thise question:

[How to delete $RECYCLE.BIN folder on external hard disk?](https://superuser.com/q/564442/65442)

I have an external USB drive that I use for all of my media files.

On my Sync tool, it shows me the hidden files and folders. I saw the `$RECYCLE.BIN` folder, selected it, and deleted it.

Now, that drive has lots of disk errors ([Error 51](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/244780)) saying,

> An error was detected on device \Device\DeviceName during a paging operation

I understand. That's because there is no recycle bin for paging operations to be done on.

OK, how to I recreate it? It is as simple as creating a directory with that name and changing the attributes?

I realize I could try that, but I don't want to do something foolish that will make the drive unusable.

**Update:**

Detailed Error message:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Disk
Date:          11/12/2015 5:56:06 AM
Event ID:      51
Task Category: None
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      NUS-PC
Description:
An error was detected on device \Device\Harddisk1\DR77 during a paging operation.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Disk" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="32772">51</EventID>
    <Level>3</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-11-12T11:56:06.652246000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>136881</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>NUS-PC</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>\Device\Harddisk1\DR77</Data>
        <Binary>030080000100000000000000330004802D0100000E0000C000000000000000000000000000000000C701F80100000000FFFFFFFF0100000058000008000000000020101240032040000000003C000000000000000000000018B1E80380FAFFFF000000000000000010D05B0380FAFFFF10507A0380FAFFFF60D26400000000008800000000000064D260000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Exact error message: **An error was detected on device \Device\Harddisk1\DR77 during a paging operation.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found something:

Create a new folder and give it this name:

`$RECYCLE.BIN.{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}`

Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, and you're done.

Maybe. I'll see how this goes.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

- Run check disk against the external drive `CHKDSK D: /F /R` with Windows
- Check the manufacturer web site for diagnostic tools to use to run against the device to identify issues, etc.—this may be device model specific too.

***Example Link:*** (http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/206395en)

---

Here's an itemized list of things to try before reinstalling, etc. just in case.

1. Try running `sfc /scannow` from an elevated command prompt and see if this finds and fixes the issue.
2. You may want to run a chkdsk too  from elevated command prompt
   `CHKDSK C: /F /R`
3. Otherwise, try a `Windows Repair` from your boot menu options or
   boot disc.

**NOTE:** I'll post more notes on Windows Repair if needed—just let me know.

I've deleted this **$RECYCLE.BIN** folder from many PCs for quick cleanup and it's never caused me any problems.

Comment: `sfc /scannow` will only run on the C: drive? This media drive is D:. I know how to edit step 2. Windows is not installed on it, so I'm guessing step 3 is irrelevant. It could just be the drive is failing.

Comment: The PC is an Intel NUC. The drive is a Seagate External Storage USB drive. I'm thinking now that the drive is actually failing. If the USB cable is bumped, you can hear that Windows sound as it detects and loses a new device.

Answer (score 1):

While Im skeptical deleting the Recycle Bin caused this issue, it could be possible.

Rather than fiddling around with possibilities, I would simply backup any data on the external disk and reformat it.  That should fix everything.

Comment: Drive is 2 weeks old. It **is** my backup drive.

Comment: @jp2code well, if you still have the data from you original sources, then there should be no issue formatting it.

Comment: I'm returning the drive. It took 3 days to copy the data to it. I just didn't want to throw that time away, but it looks like I get to do it all again.