# How to show C:\$RECYCLE.BIN?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, recycle-bin

I have an interesting problem: It's already solved, but I don't know how I did it.

In Windows Explorer, the folder $RECYCLE.BIN is shown under C:\, but I know that it's not that way by default, not even if you set hidden folders to visible.

I would like to see it, because if there are many files in the recycle bin, it's impossible to open the properties window of them all (for what reason ever). But the properties window of the C:\$RECYCLE.BIN always works.

On my laptop there is this folder, but I don't know how I did that. I will re-install the operating system soon, because of a lot of problems, but I want the folder back then so that I don't have to type it every time.

**Possible solution #1**: https://superuser.com/a/999354/650163

**Possible solution #2**: Take ownership of everything in C:\, that creates an error message that the recycle bin is corrupted, but doesn't create actual error. I don't know if the folder was visible before I did that, but afterwards it definitely was, so it might be cause.

Does one of these solutions work? Or are there other ways?

Comment: You just configure explorer to show hidden files.

Comment: From command prompt or just run you can just type in `explorer c:\$Recycle.Bin`, press `Enter` and it'll open it up with nothing further needed. Potentially a simple and easy solution with nothing else needed at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to configure your view to show hidden system files:

[image: folder and search options]

1. Open Windows Explorer
2. Highlight the operating system drive
3. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>
4. Select `Tools` on the Menu Bar
5. Select `Folder Options...`
6. Select the `View` tab
7. Select the radio button to `Show hidden files, folders, and drives`
8. Uncheck the box to disable `Hide protected operating system files`
9. Press the `OK` button

[image: $Recycle.Bin]

Comment: Wow, that actually works already. I was sure that it didn't, probably I just forgot the system file option on my work laptop. Well, thank you and have some easily earned reputation points! ;)

Comment: Always glad to help!