# What happens when a file in the D: drive that is larger than the free space in the C: drive is deleted?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, storage, recycle-bin

So imagine there is 100MB of free space in the C: drive, where the recycle bin is held. If I want to delete a file that is 1GB located in the D: drive, what happens? Is the recycle bin like any other folder or is it specific to the drive a file was deleted from?

Comment: What research have you done before you asked? That info is readily available, e.g., https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-recycle-bin-storage-settings-windows-10

Answer (score 4):

The recycle bin is held on *all* drives, files are not copied to the "system" drive for the recycle bin, they are moved to the recycle bin *on that drive*. The free space on C is irrelevant for deleting a file on the D drive.

Right click the recycle bin and go to "Properties" and you will be able to enable or adjust the size for the recycle bin on each drive.

If you want to see the recycle bin folders on each drive then you will have to [Enable the Show hidden files, folders, and drives](https://superuser.com/a/1176781/19943) option in Explorer Options. The relevant folder is `D:\$RECYCLE.BIN` and is hidden by default so without the option enabled in Explorer you will see nothing.