# External hard drive and Recycle Bin behavior

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive, recycle-bin

When my Seagate external hard drive is plugged in, its `$RECYCLE.BIN` folder automatically contains all the files contained in the Recycle Bin of the PC. Is it true that actually we don't have any Recycle Bin of external hard drive, rather it is the Recycle Bin of the PC? Why is it so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Recycle Bin is a special Windows shell folder that shows results from multiple locations. Each disk has a hidden $RECYCLE.BIN folder that contains deleted files *originally from that volume*. However, when you open the Recycle Bin, Windows doesn't show you only what's in that drive. Instead, you see a combined view showing *all* $RECYCLE.BIN folders from all mounted volumes.

You can see which disk volumes Windows will include in the Recycle Bin as follows. Simply right-click the Recycle Bin on your Desktop and click **Properties**:

[image]

If you wish to delete the Recycle Bin contents from your external drive, see [How to delete $RECYCLE.BIN folder on external hard disk?](https://superuser.com/q/564442/213131).

Comment: I hope it's clear from my answer and comments that the files from your PC **STAY** on your PC and will not go with your friend's drive.