# Cleanly remove a Recycling Bin on a partition planned for deletion

Tags: windows-10, recycle-bin

I have an old partition on disk I plan to remove from the system and it still has a recycling bin folder with files in it. I can see this from a Linux installation.

I guess Windows creates a recycling bin on every partition automatically but I don't know if they are interconnected some how.

How can I cleanly remove the recycled files and folders from this windows partition so that I can safely delete it?

I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: Regardless of this folder, you should go through your Windows recycle bin and restore/backup any files you want to keep, then you can really delete anything leftover without worry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need those files, just remove the partition (from under Windows or Linux, doesn't matter).

Recycle bins from different partitions are not interconnected. Windows shows them as one but it affects only the view, not data structure. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1258735/432690).