# My secondary HDD starts up whenever I enter Recycle Bin and some folders

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, recycle-bin

I have two SSDs for Windows and programs (C & E), and two HDDs for storage (D & F). Whenever I go into Recycle Bin that is located on C, the D HDD starts up (i.e., spins up). Even when it's empty. Same with some folders that I know are not connected to D or F. It gets a little tedious as D starts up slowly. I am curious as to why the HDD (D) starts up when it's not related to the task at hand.

Have I messed up on the partitioning or could it be something else? I have apparently all set up as "Primary Partition" as seen in the screenshot. So I'm also wondering if that is wise or if I should change it?

Disk Manager:
[image: Disk Manager]]
Disks 0 and 2 are the HDDs; 1 and 3 are the SSDs.

I can give additional info, but not sure what is needed since I have no idea as to what could be the cause of such a problem.

Comment: I believe that the issue is that `C:\$Recycle.Bin` is on the `C:` drive, but ``Desktop`` / `Recycle Bin` = `C:\$Recycle.Bin` + `D:\$Recycle.Bin` + `E:\$Recycle.Bin` + `F:\$Recycle.Bin`.  Try creating a file on your `D:` drive and delete it; then look in `Recycle Bin`.  I expect that the file will be there.  It isn’t in `C:\$Recycle.Bin`; it’s in `D:\$Recycle.Bin`.  So, when you go to `Recycle Bin`, it has to look in all the fixed (non-removable) drives.  I don’t know any way to change this behavior.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `C:\$Recycle.Bin` is on the `C:` drive,
but, [as stated here](https://superuser.com/q/1258637/354511), *the* **Recycle Bin**:

[image: Desktop / Recycle Bin]

(a.k.a. `Desktop` / `Recycle Bin`) consists of
`C:\$Recycle.Bin` + `D:\$Recycle.Bin` + `E:\$Recycle.Bin` + `F:\$Recycle.Bin`. 
Try creating a file on your `D:` drive and deleting it; then look in `Recycle Bin`. 
I expect that the file will be there. 
It isn’t in `C:\$Recycle.Bin`; it’s in `D:\$Recycle.Bin`. 
So, when you go to `Recycle Bin`,
it has to look in all the fixed (non-removable) drives.

I don’t know any way to change this behavior. 
But, if you want to not have recycle bins on your HDDs,
[the question I linked to](https://superuser.com/q/1258637/354511) suggests a possibility. 
**Disclaimer:** I have not tried this,
and so I don’t know what will happen if you do it. 
Follow these instructions at your own risk, and/or do more research.

Right-click on the Recycle Bin and select “Properties”. 
You should get something like this:

[image: Recycle Bin Properties]

- Select the `D:` drive,
- Select “Don’t move files to the Recycle Bin. 
  Remove files immediately when deleted.”
- Click on “Apply”.

Repeat for the `F:` drive.

If that doesn’t work,
try deleting the `D:\$Recycle.Bin` and `F:\$Recycle.Bin` directories
following the instructions [here](https://superuser.com/q/564442/354511).